# SSIS Script Task How To Not Send Empty Files To A Destination Location

Tags: c#, ssis

There is a ssis package that generates 5 csv files which is filled with data.

There times when a csv file that is generated is an empty file [this file is empty but it has the header columns in the file. In other words the empty file only has header columns but no data inside of it]

How can you create a script task which uses C# as a program to be like the following:
if an empty file is generated do not send file to a destination location
else you send the files since its not an empty file.

Normally the approach would be to get the file size and make a comparison that way.
The csv empty file however is 1KB in file size because there are that many columns.
And there is a chance that there can be a file that has only 1 record and that file size is still 1KB.
This means I can't do a comparison via the file size.

Is there a way to check if there is only 1 line [in this case its 2 because file generates first line which is header and then second line which is blank] and based on if that 2nd line is empty or not I can move the file?

```
public void Main()
        {
            String Source = Dts.Variables["SourceLocation].Value.ToString();
            String Destination = Dts.Variables["DestinationLocation"].Value.ToString();
            String Ext = Dts.Variables["CSVExtension"].Value.ToString();
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string destFile = string.Empty;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Source, Ext);
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = Path.Combine(Destination, fileName);
                if (s.Length > 615)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Note: Reason why I had length be greater than 615 is because there were 615 characters in the header columns the first record meaning that my logic was that if it had more that 615 characters it should copy the file if it doesn't then no file is copied.

Comment: Count the number of rows in the file, and if > 1 (header) then it is populated, otherwise delete it or do whatever you need to with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic you're missing is the [Row Count transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/row-count-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16)

Create 5 variables, of type Int32 or Int64, whatever size your output files could be. I'll assume you named them RowCountFile1, RowCountFile2, RowCountFile3, RowCountFile4, RowCountFile5.

In the Data Flow, add a Row Count immediately prior to the Flat File/Excel destination and use the Variable we just created.

When the package runs, you'll know how many rows flowed to the destination.

Now you need to determine how you're going to handle the situation.

- Do you write the files to a staging area and then move them to the final location only if the value of `@[User::RowCountFile1] > 0`. Amira outlined an excellent approach in her answer to your first question on how to handle partial files https://stackoverflow.com/a/76804952/181965
- Do you add 5 `File System Task` to delete a file and set an `Expression` on the `Disabled` property that tests whether the row count was not equal to zero (this is sounds odd but the property is Disabled so we need to have it Enabled only when the row count is zero)

Those are probably the two most common approaches a person would use with SSIS and avoiding custom code.